# Add a comment beneath a checkout field

Tags: magento2

I would like to add a little message beneath an input field on the checkout:
[image]

Is there a built-in way to do this or do I somehow need to add HTML there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<item name="notice" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Custom comment goes here</item>
```

Comment: could you please answer this question: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/301963/2358